# Index matching algorithm without hash-based data structures?

Tags: search-algorithms, hash-tables, permutations

I am programming in C, so I do not want to implement a hash-based datastructure such as a hashset or hashmap/dictionary. However, I need to solve the following task in linear time.

Given two arrays $a$ and $b$ which contain the same set of distinct integers, determine for every element of $a$ the index of the same element in $b$.

For example, if $a=[9,4,3,7]$ and $b=[3,4,7,9]$, then the output should be $[3,1,0,2]$.

Note that this becomes a very easy task when you have a hashset, because you can simply store for every element in $b$ the index, and then query the hashmap for every element of $a$.

So my question is whether there is a linear algorithm for this task that does not use any hashsets.

Comment: this site has latex. I have a proof that if $(f_1,f_2),(g_1,g_2)$ are continuous such that at least one of $f_1+g_1$ and $f_2+g_2$ has a max and a min, then $(f_1+g_1,f_2+g_2)$ is not injective. is this interesting to you?

Comment: That is certainly interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only operation allowed between any two (possibly the same) elements in the two arrays is to determine which one is the smaller one, then it will take $\Theta(n\log n)$ time in worst case for any algorithm.

This can be seen from the situation when array $a$ is sorted while array $b$ is arbitrary before we apply the algorithm. Knowing the index $I(k)$ of the element in $b$ which is the same as the $k$-th element of $a$ for all $k$, we can sort $b$ in $O(n)$ time by simply putting $b_{I(k)}$ in $k$-th position (using one temporary working space or a new result array of length $n$). However, it is well-known that it takes at least $\Theta(n\log n)$ time (comparisons) to sort $b$ in worst cases for any algorithm. So obtaining that knowledge, the index $I(k)$ for all $k$ must 
take at least $$\Theta(n\log n)- O(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$$ time as well in worst cases.

The following is a formal formulation of the conclusion above in the comparison computation model.

Let $\mathcal O$ be an oracle that can tell a fixed strict linear ordering on $E$, a set of $n$ elements. That is, on input $e,f\in E$, $\mathcal O$ outputs -1 if $e\prec f$, 0 if $e$ is $f$ and 1 otherwise. Let $a$ and $b$ are two bijections from $\{0, 1,\cdots, n-1\}$ to $E$. To output $I(0), I(1), \cdots, I(n-1)$ in that order such that $a(k)=b(I(k))$ for all $0\le k\le n-1$, it will take $\Theta(n\log n)$ queries against $\mathcal O$ in the worst case.

> whether there is a linear algorithm for this task that does not use any hashsets.

A computation model that is defined by no usage of hashset is not a well-defined computation mode. How can you check there is no usage of hashset? There are literally hundreds of ways to implement a data structure that is a hashset or looks like a hashset or looks like a hashset partially. In general, a well-defined computation model must be defined by what can be done formally.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking for an *ordering* of the elements of `a`. It sounds more like he is asking for a *mapping* i.e. *map element of a to it's position in b*; not *order elements of a according to their position in b*. Ordering will require O(nlogn) as you have astutely observed, but mapping can be done in O(n).

Comment: Exactly, I don't think OP is asking for an ordering of the element of $a$. Please read my answer carefully, especially the formal formulation. Please come to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science for a chat.

Comment: This answer abstracts "distinct integers" as "distinct elements" with a strict total order. There could be other computation models for "distinct integers" without "hashset".

Comment: Very interesting answer! Thank you! One question, though: You claim such a linear algorithm allows linear sorting. If I understand your argument correctly it goes like this. You can simply set $a$ to be $E$ in order, and set $b$ to be the unsorted list. However I do not see how you would calculate the array $a$ from the input, because $E$ is not known in advance.

Comment: Array $a$ is postulated to be $E$ in order. Array $b$ is postulated to be arbitrary. (Or you can image that before we apply the algorithm, we have used the oracle to order $a$. We leave $b$ alone). **Then** let us see what it implies when we apply the linear algorithm.

Comment: Ah I think I understand your argument! You are not saying that arbitrary lists of integers can be sorted in linear time, only that arbitrary permutations of a fixed set of integers can be sorted in linear time, which is still a contradiction if you can only compare integers. Very nicely found indeed!